# Can't connect to MySQL server on AWS. AWS says access denied to client and replaces the AWS hostname with local IPv4 address

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, ip, mysql-workbench

I am unable to access an AWS server on various software -- Microsoft Remote Desktop, MySQLWorkbench and DBeaver. The credentials are correct and the same as those of my teammates and they are able to access the server. It resolves the hostname to be the IP address and not the host address, which is strange. In the dialog box attached, it should say that Access is denied to admin@ but it says admin instead.

I have tried uninstalling and installing MySQLWorkbench multiple times. I uninstalled and installed the mysql library. I have tried changing the my.cnf files but that doesn't help either. I have a suspicion that it may be something on the server-side (AWS). I looked at the AWS console and it allows access to all IP addresses. I have tried a lot of things and still face the issue of the hostname being resolved to the local IP.

Can you please help me out?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohz7Y.png)

Comment: What about basic `mysql` command line tool? Also does not work?

Comment: You would want to check the access group and permisson . also double check the password and lastly check which port is assinged

Comment: @AkashPal I have checked the access group permissions. The default security-group is applied to the RDS instance which has an inbound rule to allow all TCP port from any IP. Similarly Netwrk ACL are also allowing inbound and outbound communication.

Comment: @Marcin yes, the mysql tool works to log in, surprisingly. It is inconvenient to use to access a large database. Whenever I use tools like DBeaver, MySQLWorkbench or Microsoft Remote Desktop, I can't get in and it says access denied even though the credentials are right.

Comment: Is it mysql 8? Mysql 8 has new way of handling credentails, which leads to some issues with some applications.